# BigO running time on some methods

Tags: java, methods, big-o, performance

Ok, these are all pretty simple methods, and there are a few of them, so I didnt want to just create multiple questions when they are all the same thing. BigO is my weakness. I just cant figure out how they come up with these answers. Is there anyway you can give me some insight into *your* thinking for analyzing running times of some of these methods? How do you break it down? How should I think when I see something like these? (specifically the second one, I dont get how thats O(1))
[image]

Comment: do you have a final in discrete structures tomorrow too?  :)  #2 is weird but I guess the answer is O(1) because apparently no matter how long the string is you get an answer of about 50

Comment: Lol no thats on Tuesday this is for an intro CS class

Comment: "(specifically the second one, I dont get how thats O(1)) " The answer key says right there: "(For large N the loop iterates ~50 times)". What part of this is difficult to understand? You apparently already know that something that iterates a fixed number of times is O(1). Surely it isn't hard to see that if we initialize the loop counter to about N, and decrement it by about N/50 each time, and stop at about 0, then we'll do about 50 loops?

Comment: I just forgot there was no difference between O(50) and O(1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function f1:
  loop 3 times
    loop n times
```

Therefore O(3*n) which is effectively O(n).

---

```
function f2:
  loop 50 times
```

O(50) is effectively O(1).

We know it will loop 50 times because it will go until `n = n - (n / 50)` is 0. For this to be true, it must iterate 50 times (`n - (n / 50)*50 = 0`).

---

```
function f3:
  loop n times
    loop n times
```

Therefore O(n^2).

---

```
function f4:
  recurse n times
```

You know this because worst case is that n = high - low + 1. Disregard the +1.
That means that n = high - low.

To terminate,

```
arr[hi] * arr[low] > 10
```

Assume that this doesn't occur until low is incremented to the highest it can go (high).

This means n = high - 0 and we must recurse up to n times.

---

```
function 5:
  loops ceil(log_2(n)) times
```

We know this because of the `m/=2`.

For example, let n=10. log_2(10) = 3.3, the ceiling of which is 4.

```
10 / 2 = 
  5 / 2 = 
   2.5 / 2 = 
    1.25 / 2 = 
      0.75
```

In total, there are 4 iterations.

Answer (score 4):

You get an n^2 analysis when performing a loop within a loop, such as the third method. 
However, the first method doesn't a n^2 timing analysis because the first loop is defined as running three times. This makes the timing for the first one 3n, but we don't care about numbers for Big-O.

The second one, introduces an interesting paradigm, where despite the fact that you have a single loop, the timing analysis is still O(1). This is because if you were to chart the timing it takes to perform this method, it wouldn't behave as O(n) for smaller numbers. For larger numbers it becomes obvious.

For the fourth method, you have an O(n) timing because you're recursive function call is passing lo + 1. This is similar to if you were using a for loop and incrementing with lo++/++lo.

The last one has a O(log n) timing because your dividing your variable by two. Just remember than anything that reminds you of a binary search will have a log n timing.

There is also another trick to timing analysis. Say you had a loop within a loop, and within each of the two loops you were reading lines from a file or popping of elements from a stack. This actually would only be a O(n) method, because a file only has a certain number of lines you can read, and a stack only has a certain number of elements you can pop off.

Answer (score 4):

The general idea of big-O notation is this: it gives a rough answer to the question "If you're given a set of N items, and you have to perform some operation repeatedly on these items, how many times will you need to perform this operation?" I say a rough answer, because it (most of the time) doesn't give a precise answer of "5*N+35", but just "N". It's like a ballpark. You don't really care about the precise answer, you just want to know how bad it will get when N gets large. So answers like O(N), O(N*N), O(logN) and O(N!) are typical, because they each represent sort of a "class" of answers, which you can compare to each other. An algorithm with O(N) will perform way better than an algorithm with O(N*N) when N gets large enough, it doesn't matter how lengthy the operation is itself.

So I break it down thus: First identify what the N will be. In the examples above it's pretty obvious - it's the size of the input array, because that determines how many times we will loop. Sometimes it's not so obvious, and sometimes you have multiple input data, so instead of just N you also get M and other letters (and then the answer is something like O(N*M*M)).

Then, when I have my N figured out, I try to identify the loop which depends on N. Actually, these two things often get identified together, as they are pretty much tied together.

And, lastly of course, I have to figure out how many iterations the program will make depending on N. And to make it easier, I don't really try to count them, just try to recognize the typical answers - O(1), O(N), O(N*N), O(logN), O(N!) or perhaps some other power of N. The O(N!) is actually pretty rare, because it's so inefficient, that implementing it would be pointless.

If you get an answer of something like N*N+N+1, then just discard the smaller ones, because, again, when N gets large, the others don't matter anymore. And ignore if the operation is repeated some fixed number of times. O(5*N) is the same as O(N), because it's the ballpark we're looking for.

**Added:** As asked in the comments, here are the analysis of the first two methods:

The first one is easy. There are only two loops, the inner one is O(N), and the outer one just repeats that 3 times. So it's still O(N). (Remember - O(3N) = O(N)).

The second one is tricky. I'm not really sure about it. After looking at it for a while I understood why it loops at most only 50 times. Since this is not dependant on N at all, it counts as O(1). However, if you were to pass it, say, an array of only 10 items, all positive, it would go into an infinite loop. That's O(∞), I guess. So which one is it? I don't know...

I don't think there's a formal way of determining the big-O number for an algorithm. It's like the halting problem. In fact, come to think of it, if you could universally determine the big-O for a piece of code, you could also determine if it ever halts or not, thus contradicting the halting problem. But that's just my musings.

Typically I just go by... dunno, sort of a "gut feeling". Once you "get" what the Big-O represents, it becomes pretty intuitive. But for complicated algorithms it's not always possible to determine. Take Quicksort for example. On average it's O(N*logN), but depending on the data it can degrade to O(N*N). The questions you'll get on the test though should have clear answers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do understand the meaning of BigO, and I am able to unroll mathematical functions to determine BigO, just havent had much practice with methods. Can you analyze the first 2 methods above so I can see how I would have arrived at the answer?

Comment: @f-Prime - well, check it out. Btw - seems like everyone has missed the infinite loop in 2nd example.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is 50 because big O is a function of the length of the input. That is if the input size changes from 1 million to 1 billion, the runtime should increase by 1000 if the function is O(N) and 1 million if it's O(n^2). However the second function runs in time 50 regardless of the input length, so it's O(1). Technically it would be O(50) but constants don't matter for big O.